# How to end fortran function without error with f2py

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I am writing a fortran function for python with f2py. Under a certain condition I would like to terminate the program and return my output without error. Unfortunately with stop the program stops with an error so that, when I call the function in python the whole script stops.

The way I do it now is to just put an conditional exit in the main loop of my function like this:

```
SUBROUTINE func(x)
...
do j1=1,N_steps

if (condition) then
 exit
end if

end do
end subroutine
```

The drawback however is that if the condition is not fulfilled it will check it on every iteration nontheless. Condition does not change in the loop. I would much prefer something like this

```
SUBROUTINE func(x)
...

if (condition) then
 stop
end if

do j1=1,N_steps
   ...
end do
end subroutine
```

but then the function does stop with an error.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Well whatever I put. If I put stop 0 the error message is 0

Comment: Ah, right.. but how does the error propagate to Python? Do you get an exception or does it terminate the process?

Comment: It terminates the process, which is (was) my problem because I couldn't catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find a duplicate, so:

**You use the `RETURN` statement to return from a function or subroutine:**

```
if (condition)  return
```

`EXIT` terminates a loop or other construct

`STOP` terminates the whole program

Comment: I am ashamed! I also didn't really find this in the internet and assumed it didn't exist.

Comment: Some people actually put `return` at the end of each procedure. I find that superfluous and ugly.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SUBROUTINE func(x)
...
if (.not. condition) then    
    do j1=1,N_steps
       ...
    end do
end if
end subroutine
```